# Up navigation with sliding transition in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application that primarily uses two activities, we'll call the first ListActivity as it contains a ListView and the other we'll call InfoActivity. When an item is clicked on the ListView the InfoActivity should be made active using a sliding transition, which I've implemented as follows

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
  //store the id of the item that was clicked
  PlacesHelper.tappedId = position;
  Intent i = new Intent(ListActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);
  finish();
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
```

When I click an item and view it, the transition works beautifully. However, using the back button or the Up button(because ListActivity is a parent to InfoActivity) causes both Activities to disappear(not using the sliding transition either) and go back to LoadingActivity.

What is causing this to happen? Is there something seriously wrong with my implementation of the transition?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I got it! Calling finish() apparently removes the Activity from memory, so I had to remove that line.

The up button in the ActionBar and the back button still didn't do the sliding transition, but that was easily fixed by overriding backPressed() and onOptionsItemSelected() and using overridePendingTransition().

Final code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
  //store the id of the item that was clicked
  PlacesHelper.tappedId = position;
  Intent i = new Intent(ListActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
```

I hope this helps someone!